# Placing two different floats next to each other (independent, float-specific captions)

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, memoir

I have two floats, a figure and an algorithm (new floating environment). I want then to be placed next to each other each using half the linewidth (or 48%, or whatever looks the nicest). I have tried using minipage, but that does (of course) note work as minipages does not float. I have included an example of the figure and the algorithm I need to place next to each other and a picture of the desired result.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Tikz is used to draw the figure
\usepackage{tikz}

% Just some changes to the margins
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{0.875}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{1.2}  
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]      

% The new floating environment
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
fileext=los,
listname=List of Algorithms,
name=Algorithm,
placement=tbp,
within=chapter,
]{algorithm}

\begin{document}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale =0.5]
            \draw [fill] (0,6) circle [radius=0.08];
            \node [left] at (0,6) {$SP_1$};    
            \draw [fill] (2,8) circle [radius=0.08];
            \node [right] at (2,8) {$DP_0$};    
            \draw [fill] (2,4) circle [radius=0.08];
            \node [left] at (2,4) {$SP_2$};    
            \draw [fill] (4,6) circle [radius=0.08];
            \node [right] at (4,6) {$DP_1$};    
            \draw [fill] (4,2) circle [radius=0.08];
            \node [left] at (4,2) {$SP_3$};    
            \draw [fill] (6,4) circle [radius=0.08];
            \node [right] at (6,4) {$DP_2$};    
            \draw [fill] (8,2) circle [radius=0.08];
            \node [right] at (8,2) {$DP_3$};    
            \draw (0,6)--(2,8);
            \draw (4,6)--(2,8);
            \draw (4,6)--(2,4);
            \draw (4,6)--(6,4);
            \draw (0,6)--(2,8);
            \draw (6,4)--(4,2);
            \draw (6,4)--(8,2);


            \node [left] at (1,7) {$\sum_{j\in\Omega_1}x_j\leq \gamma$};
            \node [right] at (3,7) {$\sum_{j\in\Omega_1}x_j\geq \gamma+1$};

            \draw[white,fill=white] (4,-2.5) circle[radius = 0.08];
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{The cut--and--solve search tree.}\label{fig:CutAndSolveSearchTree}%
        \end{figure}

        \begin{algorithm}
        \fbox{
            \parbox{0.94\linewidth}{

                \textbf{Input:} A mixed inter programming problem.\\
                \textbf{Output:} An optimal solution $x^*$ to a problem.
                \begin{description}
                    \item[Step 1] (Initialization) Set $L=-\infty$, $UB=\infty$, and set the set of piecing cuts $H = \emptyset$. 
                    \item[Step 2] (Dense problem) Solve a relaxation of the problem with all piercing cuts in $H$ added. Let the solution value be $L$.
                    \item[Step 3] (Termination check) If $L\geq UB$, return the incumbent.
                    \item[Step 4] (Piercing cut selection) Select an index set variables $\Omega$ for the piercing cut.
                    \item[Step 5] (Sparse problem) Solve the problem with $x_j=0$ for all $j\in\Omega$.
                    \item[Step 6] (Incumbent update) If the solution found in Step 4 improves the incumbent, then update $UB$. If $L\geq UB$, return the incumbent.
                    \item[Step 7] (Adding piercing cut) Add piercing cut $\sum_{j\in\Omega}x_j\geq 1$ to $H$ and go to Step 1.
                \end{description}
            }
        }
        \caption{Algorithm}{A description of a generic cut--and--solve algorithm.}\label{alg:CutAndSolveGeneric}
        \end{algorithm} 
\end{document}
```

And this is the desired result

[image: Desired result]

Comment: You'll have to place them into the same float construction (either `figure` or `algorithm` and then use the `caption` package and its `\captionof` feature to change the type of the other float.

Comment: I imagine that when you say "place them into the same float construction" you mean something like using subfloat inside a e.g. figure environment in order for the alg and the fig to place next to each other? However, when I place both the figure and th algorithm in a fig-env, each in separate subfloats, and use the \captionof I get the quite funky message *You can't use \hrule here except with leaders*. But I don't use any \hrule's (intentionally).

Comment: no need for subfloat, these are not two subinstances of, say, figure, just wrap them in a minipage each, and include the caption in each minipage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Tikz is used to draw the figure
\usepackage{tikz}

% Just some changes to the margins
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{0.875}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{1.2}  
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]      

\usepackage{caption}


% The new floating environment
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
fileext=los,
listname=List of Algorithms,
name=Algorithm,
placement=tbp,
within=chapter,
]{algorithm}

\begin{document}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
              \centering
              some image
            \end{minipage}
            \hfill
            \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
              \begin{framed}
                some algorithm
              \end{framed}
           \end{minipage}

           \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
                           \caption{The cut--and--solve search
                tree.}\label{fig:CutAndSolveSearchTree}%
           \end{minipage}
           \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
             \captionof{algorithm}{A description of a generic
               cut--and--solve
               algorithm.}\label{alg:CutAndSolveGeneric}
           \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh. Would definitely not have thought of that. Works like a charm, though!